# MYSQL IN Optimisation

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, exists

I'm having trouble adapting my SQL query's IN statement to a EXISTS. I understand IN is slower and this seems to be reflected in the query's performance.

```
SELECT 
    t.dt as 'Log Time',
    sn.name as 'Snake Name',
    sen.type as 'Sensor Type',
    t.temp as Temperature
FROM
    temps as t
        JOIN
    sensors as sen ON t.sensor = sen.sensorid
        JOIN
    locations as l ON sen.location = l.id
        JOIN
    snakes as sn ON sen.location = sn.location
WHERE
    dt IN (SELECT 
            max(dt)
        FROM
            temps
        GROUP BY sensor)
ORDER BY sn.name ASC , sen.type DESC
;
```

Any ideas of how to improve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Run it with [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) and you'll get some insight as to whether it's hitting indices, etc.

Comment: Have you actually timed this statement in real application?  Is it really problematic? "Don't fix it if it ain't broken".

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `IN (SELECT subquery)` is that MySQL "optimizes" it with what is often a very poor performance choice.

According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html), a query with a template like this:

> > WHERE **outer_expr** IN (SELECT **inner_expr** FROM ... WHERE **subquery_where**)

Is automatically converted by the optimizer to this:

> > WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE **subquery_where** AND **outer_expr**=**inner_expr**)

The problem is that this subquery is executed for every row in the outer `SELECT`. If we are talking about hundreds, thousands, or even hundreds of thousands of rows before `WHERE`, MySQL will take quite a while to digest this thing, iterating the same table over and over looking for each match individually. Not cool!

The solution is to force it to create and `JOIN` with a temporary table. The idea is that despite the fact of creating a temporary table is slower and takes more memory than a simple query, it is certainly faster than thousands of queries. So this is what you are going to do:

```
SELECT 
    t.dt `Log Time`,
    sn.name `Snake Name`,
    sen.type `Sensor Type`,
    t.temp `Temperature`
FROM
    temps t
        JOIN
    sensors sen ON t.sensor = sen.sensorid
        JOIN
    locations l ON sen.location = l.id
        JOIN
    snakes sn ON sen.location = sn.location
        JOIN
    (SELECT sensor, MAX(dt) maxdt FROM temps GROUP BY sensor) m
        ON m.maxdt = t.dt AND m.sensor = t.sensor
ORDER BY sn.name ASC, sen.type DESC;
```

When you `JOIN` with a subquery `SELECT` it won't make dumb assumptions. A temporary table is created behind the scene, and it will be performing a `JOIN` with it just as you told it to.

However, observe that this can be optimized further. We can do this by keeping a low number of records in game as you `JOIN` tables. The sooner you withdraw records you don't need from the query, the less MySQL will have to process on the subsequent `JOIN`s and faster it will go. You can, for instance, filter the rows you need from `temps` straight from the beginning, just by reorganizing the `JOIN` sequence:

```
SELECT 
    t.dt `Log Time`,
    sn.name `Snake Name`,
    sen.type `Sensor Type`,
    t.temp `Temperature`
FROM
    (SELECT sensor, MAX(dt) maxdt FROM temps GROUP BY sensor) m
        JOIN
    temps t ON m.maxdt = t.dt AND m.sensor = t.sensor
        JOIN
    sensors sen ON t.sensor = sen.sensorid
        JOIN
    locations l ON sen.location = l.id
        JOIN
    snakes sn ON sen.location = sn.location
ORDER BY sn.name ASC, sen.type DESC;
```

This seemingly simple change is very significative for performance, this query should be considerably faster than the first one, specially if `temps` is a big table.

You can also use `SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN ...` to enforce the order of `JOIN`s in case it performs even better (it usually does).

Answer (score 0):

You are right, `IN` subqueries are *usually* slower than `EXISTS`.

`EXISTS` works differently because you can use previous columns directly in it. You can also improve by using `LIMIT` to limit your subset to only the amount you really need. When using `EXISTS`, it doesn't matter what you select because it just asks: is there at least 1 row returned or not.

Make sure to use the prefix on every column.

```
SELECT 
    t.dt as 'Log Time',
    sn.name as 'Snake Name',
    sen.type as 'Sensor Type',
    t.temp as Temperature
FROM
    temps as t
        JOIN
    sensors as sen ON t.sensor = sen.sensorid
        JOIN
    locations as l ON sen.location = l.id
        JOIN
    snakes as sn ON sen.location = sn.location
WHERE
    EXISTS(
        SELECT 'hi'
        FROM   temps
        GROUP  BY temps.sensor
        HAVING max(temps.dt) = t.dt
        LIMIT 1
    )
ORDER BY sn.name ASC , sen.type DESC
;
```

Comment: Your subselect looks rather dodgy... I am pretty sure it won't produce correct values.

Comment: @AleksG how bout now?

Comment: That will produce an error.  The correct syntax will be `SELECT ... FROM ... GROUP BY ... HAVING max(temps.dt) = t.dt LIMIT 1` Yet, queries with `HAVING` a generally slow, therefore I'm not sure whether in this case using `EXISTS` would produce any benefit.

Comment: @AleksG Let OP try this. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: @DanFromGermany my original query takes 52.604 sec and returns 6 row, one for each distinct sensor ID. Your query takes 50.466 sec and returns only 1 row, so it doesn't seem to be work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out both EXISTS and IN aren't the optimal solution. After having a play around I came up with the following:

```
SELECT distinct
    t.dt as 'Log Time',
    sn.name as 'Snake Name',
    sen.type as 'Sensor Type',
    t.temp as Temperature
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        temps
    ORDER BY dt DESC) as t
        JOIN
    sensors as sen ON t.sensor = sen.sensorid
        JOIN
    locations as l ON sen.location = l.id
        JOIN
    snakes as sn ON sen.location = sn.location
WHERE
    dt != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
GROUP BY sensor
ORDER BY sn.name ASC , sen.type DESC
```

Which takes 0.047 sec to run as oppose to the original ~50 sec query.

Comment: This is not quite the same thing. What if more than one `dt` in the same `sensor` is not `0000-00-00 00:00:00`? Your `GROUP BY sensor` will fetch the first match for each sensor regardless if it's `dt` is the `MAX(dt)` for that sensor.

Answer (score 0):

Although it appears you have a solution and very good time, Havenard has a good point about not necessarilyt getting correct per sensor.  I would propose the following.

On your temps table, have an index on (sensor, dt), then, your first from will be a select grouped by each sensor, so each sensor appears once with its respective date/time.  Then, use that as basis to rejoin to temps by that same sensor/max(dt) and get rest of the data.

This is very close to what Havenard posted except I am moving my pre-query up front and adding "STRAIGHT_JOIN" to force the join in the order as written.  Start with the very limited set via max date/time, then join the rest to get the descriptions and temp info.

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      t.dt `Log Time`,
      sn.name `Snake Name`,
      sen.type `Sensor Type`,
      t.temp `Temperature`
   FROM
      ( select t1.sensor, max( t1.dt ) as MaxDT
           from temps t1
           group by t1.sensor ) PreQuery
         JOIN temps t
            on PreQuery.sensor = t.sensor
           AND PreQuery.MaxDT = t.dt
        JOIN sensors sen 
           ON PreQuery.sensor = sen.sensorid
           JOIN locations l 
              ON sen.location = l.id
           JOIN snakes sn 
              ON sen.location = sn.location
   ORDER BY 
      sn.name,
      sen.type DESC;
```